# What are differences between healthpoints and shields?

Tags: apex-legends

Afaics shields do not regenerate automatically and seem to be "additional healthpoints" on top of the regular healthpoints.

- Do shields take 100% of damage?
- Are shields affected by better armor?
- Are there upgrades for shields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between the two are what items you use to replenish them. In addition, only health will take damage from being outside the ring.

The shield/armor upgrades (white to blue to purple/yellow) give 50/75/100 maximum shields. Each bar in the HUD is worth 25.

Comment: Also, Caustic's poison goes through shields.

Comment: Still, when you are being shot, both health and shield are deducted. So shield must work somehow to decrease damage, not replace health.

Comment: @lentinant I've never experienced health being dropped before shields.